# Timer.start() unexpectedly?

Tags: c#, forms, timer

```
private void PlayerClockInPanelControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializedMouseDownEvent();
}

private void InitializedMouseDownEvent() 
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowErrorMessage("Hello");
        aTimer.Stop();
    }

private void picturebox_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Start();
    }


private void picturebox_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Stop();
    }
```

My idea was, the timer should start only when `MouseDown` event is fired but now once the form loads, it displays "Hello" every second. 
As mentioned in the code there is only `aTimer.Start()` being called during `MouseDown` event. May I know what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this behaviour because there is no difference between `timer.Start()` and `timer.Enabled = true` (and also `timer.Stop()` and `timer.Enabled = false`). For this reason if you call `timer.Enabled = tru`e in your `formLoad` you start the timer.
For more information check [this MDSN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled.aspx)